# Getting a character of a string from list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, string

So I have this code:

```
rBlock1=[{"layer1" : "bbbbb"}, {"layer2" : "ccccc"}];
```

I'm getting a string called "layer1" using this:

```
rBlock1[0]["layer1"]
```

and it returns: `bbbbb`, how do I get specific character from this string, for example 3rd character `(bb**b**bb)`?

Comment: `rBlock1[0]["layer1"][2]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the character number (don't forget it start from 0)

```
>>> rBlock1 =[{"layer1" : "bbbbb"}, {"layer2" : "ccccc"}];
>>> rBlock1[0]["layer1"][2]
'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a single character from a string given its index, use `mystring[index]`. For example, to get the third character from `mystring`, use `mystring[2]`. Note that all indexes are zero based.

So, just append `[2]` to `rBlock1[0]["layer1"]`:

```
rBlock1=[{"layer1" : "bbbbb"}, {"layer2" : "ccccc"}];
rBlock1[0]["layer1"][2]; # Returns the third b of "layer1"
```